# Javascript, misunderstanding the lifecycle of a CustomHTMLElement: clarification needed

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am currently studying CustomHtmlElements and I have a misunderstanding about the order in which the constructors are invoked.

For example, if I have two CustomHtmlElements:

```js
class ExForm extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(`${this.getAttribute('name')} constructor ${performance.now()}`);
    //debugger;
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(`${this.getAttribute('name')} connected ${performance.now()}`);
  }
}

customElements.define("ex-form", ExForm);

class ExInput extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    console.log(`${this.getAttribute('name')} constructor ${performance.now()}`);
    //debugger;
  }
  
   connectedCallback() {
    console.log(`${this.getAttribute('name')} connected ${performance.now()}`);
  }
}

customElements.define("ex-input", ExInput);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ex-form name="form1">
      <ex-input name="input1" ></ex-input>
    </ex-form>
    <ex-form name="form2">
      <ex-input name="input2"></ex-input>
    </ex-form>
  </body>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

I was expecting that the order of constructors execution would be:

form1, input1, form2, input2

However, when I executed the code, the order was:

form1, form2, input1, input2

Can someone clarify why there is a discrepancy between the order of constructor execution and the order in which the HTML elements are rendered to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when the Web Component is defined.

Your JS code in a StackOverflow Code snippet will run  ***after* the DOM is parsed**, thus will ***upgrade*** the existing Custom Elements (initially parsed as `HTMLUnknownElement`)

`ex-form` is defined first, so **all** existing `<ex-form>` will be upgraded first.
Then `ex-input` is defined, and **all** existing `<ex-input>` are upgraded next.

(see snippet below) If you move the **declaration** ***before*** the DOM is parsed, you get the order you expect:

[image]

In general: don't rely on order in the DOM, you have no control on when the user/developer loads your Web Component file.

There is `customElements.whenDefined( )` if you need to check for dependencies.

```html
<script>
  class BaseClass extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      console.log(`constructor ${this.nodeName} `, this.innerHTML);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      console.log(`${this.nodeName} connected ${this.innerHTML}`);
    }
  }
  customElements.define("ex-form", class extends BaseClass {});
  customElements.define("ex-input", class extends BaseClass {});
</script>
<ex-form>
  <ex-input></ex-input>
  <ex-input></ex-input>
</ex-form>
<ex-form>
  <ex-input></ex-input>
</ex-form>
```

Comment: Thanks Danny for the explanation. Your point of view was really helpful and gave me a good starting point to understand the process better. I can see now that my question involved a lot of details about how the browser reads HTML, and your answer has helped me to get a better handle on that. If no one else provides a more in-depth explanation, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I added _``ex-form`` is defined **first**_, to explain the Why better.